# Nodejs ./bin/www script not running on startup

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm learning node.js. I setup node and express on my machine. Then I used express auto project generator to setup a basic project. I could see my localhost:3000 page. But then something happened and it suddenly stopped working (obviously im not sure what happend).

I tried debugging and adding some console statements. It turns out ./bin/www file which is supposed to run on start up (specified in package.json) is not getting executed at all.

If I just add these 2 lines of code from ./bin/www to my app.js file everything seems to work fine.

```
var port = (process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.listen(port);
```

So I think culprit is bin/www file but I'm not sure why it is not getting executed at all?

In my package.json file I have this

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
```

Let me know if I should be posting any other information that can be helpful.

Comment: how are you running app?  using npm start or node app.js

Comment: by running command  node app.js

Comment: what is the difference between those 2? I have never heard anything about npm start

Comment: If there is .bin/www in your applicaion that means you are using Express 4.0 . In case of Express 3.0 we need to run command 'node app.js' but in case of Express 4.0 we need to run command 'npm start' to run nodeJS application.
So , here seems you are using Express 4.0, so run your application through 'npm start'

Answer (score 2):

After using `npm start` if the terminal shows
 **>node ./bin/www**  than it means your server is already running. 
It will work just fine. Just **manually** paste: **http://localhost:3000/** on your browser. You will get the braintree drop-in UI as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the scripts to:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www/app.js"
  },
```

and then use the command `npm start` Hope that helps!

Comment: yes running npm start instead of node app.js worked, can you please explain why and what is the difference between the two?

Comment: npm start calls node to execute a file. You created app.js in ./bin/www folder. When you say node <directory>, the javascript file that you want to run MUST be named index.js, if you want to run the javascript file that is not named index.js, you have to run the file as node <file name>.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not started node server.
Try adding following in `app.js` :

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

Now start your server using `node app`